# Oracle XmlAgg function with case when

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

I have a query with joined tables where there are two columns that need to be compared and then need to be concatinated

```
select tc.id$ as id, case
when a.comment is null and b.comment is null then ''
when a.comment is null and b.comment is not null then RTRIM (XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (E,XMLATTRIBUTES ('Updated from null -> ' || b.comment || ';' AS "Seg"))ORDER BY b.comment ASC).EXTRACT ('./E[not(@Seg = preceding-sibling::E/@Seg)]/@Seg'),';')
when a.comment is not null and b.comment is null then RTRIM (XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (E,XMLATTRIBUTES ('Updated to null from || ' a.comment || ';' AS "Seg"))ORDER BY a.comment ASC).EXTRACT ('./E[not(@Seg = preceding-sibling::E/@Seg)]/@Seg'),';')
when a.comment is not null and b.comment is not null and a.comment <> b.comment then
    RTRIM (XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (E,XMLATTRIBUTES ('Updated from '|| a.comment || '->' || b.comment ||';' AS "Seg"))ORDER BY a.comment ASC).EXTRACT ('./E[not(@Seg = preceding-sibling::E/@Seg)]/@Seg'),';')
else ''end as TESTER_COMMENT_UPDATED from tableA tc left join htableA a on a.id$=tc.id$ left join htableA b on b.id$=tc.id$group by tc.id$
```

Unfortunately I am getting string concatenation is too long

so tried by adding.getClobVal() after `EXTRACT ('./E[not(@Seg = preceding-sibling::E/@Seg)]/@Seg')`

Unfortunately it is throwing inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got CLOB error

so tried by adding case statements inside xml attributes like below:

```
        RTRIM (XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (E,XMLATTRIBUTES (case 
when a.comment is not null and b.comment is not null and a.comment <> b.comment then
      'Updated from ' || a.comment || '->' || b.comment when a.comment is null and b.comment is not null then 'Updated from null -> ' || b.comment
      when a.comment is not null and b.comment is null then 'Updated to null from ' || a.comment
    else '' end as seg

))).EXTRACT ('./E[not(@Seg = preceding-sibling::E/@Seg)]/@Seg').getClobVal(),';')
```

script is executing with out errors but no data output. Is there a way to use xmlaggs with case when or nested?

Comment: You may be trying to fix the wrong problem; the issue is likely to be that the attribute value you are generating is too long, not that the extract (which is already a CLOB)  is too long. You're concatenating the `comment` (which isn't a valid column name, BTW) string with other strings, so if a comment exceeds 3984 chars (if I'm counting right) or an old/new comment pair exceeds 3998 chars in total, the attribute value will be more than 4000 chars - and throw this error. Try it without the aggregation, and check the maximum comment length in each table.

Comment: comment length is 4000 chars. and when I try to concatenate a.comment with b.comment then also getting same error

Comment: Then you'll need to convert at least the first literal part to a CLOB with `to_clob()`; the concatenation will then produce a CLOB. But it seems XMLAttribute doesn't allow CLOBs. XMLElement does though... Why are you using attributes here; and what is the preceding-sibling part for - removing duplicates?

Comment: Your joins also don't seem to make sense; if `htablea` has multiple comments for an `id$`, don't you need to get them all in chronological order, and then have your aggregation show them in that order - rather than getting all combinations (i.e. a cartesian product of that table with itself?) and ordering them by the comment text? Is there a date/timestamp column on that table to order them by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally It worked

```
when a.comment is null and b.comment is null then null
when a.comment is null and b.comment is not null then  
    XMLELEMENT (E,
      XMLELEMENT(c1, 'Updated from '''' to: '),
      XMLELEMENT(c2, b.comment)
    ).extract('//text()').getClobVal()  
when a.comment is not null and b.comment is null then 
    XMLELEMENT (E,
      XMLELEMENT(c1, 'Updated to '''' from: '),
      XMLELEMENT(c2, a.comment)
    ).extract('//text()').getClobVal() 
when a.comment is not null and b.comment is not null and a.comment <> b.comment then 
    XMLELEMENT (E,
      XMLELEMENT(s, 'Updated from: ' ||CHR(13)),
      XMLELEMENT(c1, a.comment),
      XMLELEMENT(sep, CHR(13) ||' to: ' || CHR(13)),
      XMLELEMENT(c2, b.comment)
    ).extract('//text()').getClobVal()
```